# Scraping PDF - Checking word frequency on specified keywords

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping, jupyter-notebook, nltk

I've created a parser that scrapes keywords from a PDF document. Currently, this scrapes the top keyword as well as shows the frequency (how many times) the words been repeated in the document.

At this point, I'm looking to check the frequency of specific keywords however when entering the desired keyword, it joins the word together with the top word and gives the same frequency.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to check the frequency of the keyword 1.) "GRI" 2.) "CDP"

Would great appreciate anyone's help here!

```
import pandas as pd
import textract
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import nltk

nltk.download('stopwords')

pdffileobj=open('sample.pdf', 'rb')
pdfreader=PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdffileobj)
num_pages=pdfreader.numPages
count = 0
text= " "

while count < num_pages:
    pageObj = pdfreader.getPage(count)
    count +=1
    text += pageObj.extractText()

if text != "":
   text = text
else:
   text = textract.process(fileurl, method='tesseract', language='eng')

nltk.download('punkt')
tokens=word_tokenize(text)

punctuations = ['(',')',';',':','[',']',',','!','=','==','<','>','@','#','$','%','^','&','*','.','//','{','}','...','``','+',"''",]

stop_words = stopwords.words('english')

keywords = [word for word in tokens if not word in stop_words and not word in punctuations]

# print(keywords)
#At this point all the keywords in the document show up 

freq = pd.Series(' '.join(keywords).split()).value_counts()

#Print results show with frequency
print(freq)
```

Comment: The `' '.join(keywords).split()` is doing work and then immediately undoing it - just put `keywords` here.

Comment: Thank you @DanR for your response. I've taken out the contents reflected in your comment and just left keywords and value_counts: 

**freq = pd.Series(keywords).value_counts('GRI')**

When I print the freq now it reflects a percentage of the same top key words rather than contents in the (i.e., value_count('GRI')) 

Unfortunately not returning the text value. Any ideas for next steps here?

Answer (score 0):

To get a single word's frequency from Pandas' `value_counts()` output, you just do

```
freq['word_you_want']
```